# What would be the recommended way to integrate Microsoft Team Foundation Server into an iOS application

Tags: ios, tfs, cross-platform, tfs-sdk, azure-devops

I am looking to create an application that allows a user to update Microsoft Team Foundation Server work items when performing certain things in the app.

Has anyone done anything similar themselves and if so what is the best way to make the updates to the TFS work items from within the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a Java API which is linked below:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=22616

Other than that a few google searches resulted in the following discoveries:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb130146.aspx

The link below tells you how you can create new work items via a URL:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb822136%28v=VS.90%29.aspx

** As per jessehouwing's comment below ***

This only works on 2008 and 2010 I suspect. There migth be a similar Url for 2012 and 2013, but the whole WebAccess feature was rebuilt using ASP.NET MVC instead of WebForms, so the wi.aspx no longer exists. I'm not aware of an alternative.

Comment: That posting to url only works on 2008 and 2010 I suspect. There migth be a similar Url for 2012 and 2013, but the whole WebAccess feature was rebuilt using ASP.NET MVC instead of WebForms, so the wi.aspx no longer exists. I'm not aware of an alternative.

Comment: Fantastic comment, thanks - I shall update the answer. I stumbled across this as he had asked a similar question relating to Jira which I am more experienced with. I have never used TFS myself.

Answer (score 1):

[Visual Studio Online an Team Foundation Server 2013 are gaining more and more json based REST Api](http://www.visualstudio.com/integrate/reference/reference-vso-overview-vsi)'s and have recently been upgraded to support OAuth for authentication. Some of these API's are still in preview, but they're a great resource for a mobile platform client.

For older versions of Team Foundation Server and the On-premise version you can either [install the OData](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/briankel/archive/2013/01/07/odata-service-for-team-foundation-server-v2.aspx) service, or build a custom webservice that employs the [TFS Client Object Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb130323.aspx) internally to create the work items.

Should you want to build your webservice on top of a non-microsoft-platform, then you can employ the [Java SDK for Team Foundation Server](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=22616). This will allow you to communicate directly to TFS from a Linux or Mac server.

[TFS 2013.4 will be able to show more pages in full screen mode without any chrome around it](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2014/09/02/update-4-ctp1-now-available.aspx#fullscreen).

Comment: Be aware that there are licensing restrictions for users posting items to TFS. They should only be able to read their own workitems and they're not allowed to freely query work items.

Comment: No need to create a custom web service. The client object model is yet another proxy that calls TFS's web services

Comment: Yes, but connecting directly against the TFS Web Services is unsupported. The Client Object Model is, for now, the way to go. Also, you won't want to expose the TFS webservices to the whole internet with a well known set of credentials.

Comment: This would be perfect, more than anything I just need to be able to update the Status of a work Item and add some form of comment. At a real push I want to change the assignee but this is not a requirement. Whilst I am fluent with iOS, I have never used Microsoft product before now.

Comment: Updated with the new REST Api documentation